# How to replace CSS style using PHP?

Tags: php, css, preg-replace, preg-match-all

**Short question :** I've a $css variable containing CSS, I would like to find a given style (in my case the "body" one) in that variable and replace it with custom style.

**Basic input output** :

```
/* blablabla */
body {
    background-color:#d0e4fe;
    font-family: 'Afamily', sanas-serif;
}
span {
    padding: 5px
}
h1 {
    color:orange;
    text-align:center;
}
body {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
}
p {
    font-family:"Times New Roman";
    font-size:20px;
}
```

We call magicFunction():

```
echo magicFunction($css, 'font-color: pink; font-weight: bold;');
```

And we get :

```
/* blablabla */
body {
    font-color: pink; font-weight: bold;
}
span {
    padding: 5px
}
h1 {
    color:orange;
    text-align:center;
}
p {
    font-family:"Times New Roman";
    font-size:20px;
}
```

**What's wrong ?** Basically I'm stucked here

```
$bodyPattern = '/body\s\{[.|\s]*/m';
$found = preg_match_all($bodyPattern, $css, $matches);
```

It found only output stuff like :

```
"body {
   '"
```

After the line return ... nothing.

Of course once I'll have the right regexp pattern I'll use preg_replace.

**Why I want to do that** : I want to apply [CssToInlineStyle](http://classes.verkoyen.eu/css_to_inline_styles) using my website CSS to build a newsletter, I'd like to change only the body style to avoid some style to be applied (like a background color). EDIT : This point is mentioned to let you know the "why", feel free to comment and give your view point on that, but please consider only the above question as what you're supposed to answer.

Comment: Did you first wonder if email clients accept css like that?

Comment: Yes they do, at least GMail accepts it, if the rendering is not that good on others that's not a big deal

Comment: I do really appreciate all the unexplained down votes !

Comment: Why on earth is this downvoted so aggressively?

Comment: @Robinv.G. : maybe the cause is "font-color: pink", I admit that's really bad taste !

Comment: @MihaiIorga : for your information Facebook is sending email this way

Answer (score 1):

I believe the regex your after is this:
`body {(([a-zA-Z0-9:;#%\(\)\'\-])*\s*)*}` - you'll need to format it properly for multiline in php.

You need to match every character **except** `{` and `}` to ensure you only capture the body style and not all styles.

I also reccomend using [this site](http://regexpal.com/) to test regex before trying to use it. I do agree with the other comments, I think what your doing is a little mad.. but in the words of Norman Bates 'We all go a little mad sometimes', I know I have. Hope this helps.

**EDIT:**

```
<?php
    $css = "body { \n
        color:#899890;\n
        }";
    $pattern = '/body(\s){0,1}{(([a-zA-Z0-9:;#%\(\)\'\-])*\s*)*}/m';
    $found = preg_match_all($pattern, $css, $matches);

    print_r($matches);
?>
```

produces:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => body { 

        color:#899890;

        }
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => ;
        )

)
```

It seems to work for me.

Comment: Thanks, the first answer that was actually an answer (and that quote makes it great). I know this design is not perfect, but I accept becoming a little mad since no other approach seems a little better TMHO. I'm testing that ASAP.

Comment: It doesn't work on multiline, I theory the \s meta character and the m options in the pattern should do the job, don't they ?

Comment: Thanks, it works on your sample code, but not on my whole CSS, I reproduce the problem : 1/ quotes aren't correctly handled 2/ multi body entries aren't returned

Answer (score 0):

Either you [serve your CSS-file with PHP](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/supercharge-your-css-with-php-under-the-hood/). Or you use something like [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) for using variables in your CSS.

Parsing the CSS with PHP and replace variables using regex will result in [very bad performance](http://lzone.de/articles/php-string-search.htm) and put a big load on your server.

Comment: My question was not to serve a CSS from my server since external file loading are blocked by many clients. I'm already using LESS but in my case I don't think I can write anything to erase previous declarations. I'm not concerned by performances issue since I run this part of the code only once.

Answer (score 0):

I would use css like this.

```
<style>
<? include style.php;?>
</style>
```

Now on style.php

```
body { <? magicFunction('font-color: pink; font-weight: bold;');
?> 
}

h1 {
    color:orange;
    text-align:center;
}
p {
    font-family:"Times New Roman";
    font-size:20px;
}
```

And magicFunction would be like this

```
function magicFunction($style) {
    echo $style;
}
```

Comment: This is an ugly trick, but since I use LESS I do not think embedded PHP code would do anything good. This also put dependencies in the style for a small feature of my app.

Comment: @AsTeR: it's an ugly trick alright, but instead of embedding PHP in LESS (which would most likely result in compile error), it would be much easier to generate a LESS file from PHP.

Comment: Which would require to run PHP, then to run less and this while a client is waiting ... bad idea

Answer (score 0):

one way to avoid needing to do this is by exploiting the cascading feature of CSS:

```
body {
    background-color:#d0e4fe;
    font-family: 'Afamily', sanas-serif;
}

<? if (...): ?>
    body {
        // overrides the definitions applied above
        background-color: inherit;
        font-family: inherit;

        // and define your own rules
        font-color: pink; 
        font-weight: bold;
    }
<? endif; ?>
```

Comment: see @vusan answer and my comment

Comment: @AsTeR: I was not suggesting embedded PHP, instead you put this code on the HTML file; the if statement can alternatively be replaced with a /* */ if you don't even use PHP for generating the HTML.

Comment: Well TMHO that's the same approach

Comment: @AsTeR: why? AFAICT, there is no trickery needed. Unless you have another requirement that you're not telling.

Comment: @AsTeR: in fact, since you already have the $css in a variable, you can just concatenate your new rules to that variable if you wish.

Comment: Yes, but that's not my question. The description of my needs are there has extra information, I'm not looking for a workaround.

Comment: @AsTeR: AFAICT, it's perfectly compatible with the "why" part of your question.

Comment: @AsTeR: I just have to say that I don't get you; you're basically using a slippery workaround with regex replacement, while CSS has formally defined cascading feature built in. But whatever floats your boat, I guess.

Comment: Reset previous statements in CSS would just mean to know which one have been set which implies. Does that answer ?